# How come some site urls do not include a file extension?

Tags: url, file-extension

I was browsing the internet and noticed, YouTube, for example, contains a URL like this to denote a video page: `http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gwS1tGLB0vc`.

My site uses a URL like this for a topic page: `http://www.example.com/page.php?topic_id=6f3246d0sdf42c2jb67abba60ce33d5cc`.

The difference is, if you haven't already noticed that on youtube, there is no file extension for their watch page, so I am wondering, *why do some sites not use file extensions and what use does it serve?*

Answer (score 40, accepted):

File extensions are not used because of the idea that URIs (and therefore URLs) should be independent of implementation - if you want to access the CDC's information about food safety, you should be able to go to https://www.cdc.gov/foodsafety (for example).  Whether the CDC's servers are using PHP or Python or Perl doesn't matter to the end-user, so they don't need to see it. The end-user doesn't care how the page was generated, because all languages serving a webpage output the same HTML, CSS, and the like, and the user is just viewing the page in their web browser.

Most web frameworks build this functionality in by default, precisely for this reason, and it can be accomplished regardless with URL rewriting in most webservers.  This ideal is codified in the W3C Style Guide, which is undoubtedly a big factor in this idea being so widely accepted.  It's outlined in their guide, ["Cool URIs Don't Change"](http://www.w3.org/Provider/Style/URI.html), which should clear things up if you still don't quite understand the reasoning here.  That document is the go-to statement on the issue, and the de facto standard for frameworks.

It is worth noting that usually files that end up being *downloaded* (and sometimes data files used in AJAX) will still have their file extensions intact - http://example.com/song.mp3 or http://example.com/whitepaper.pdf - because they are intended to be saved to the end-user's computer, where file extensions matter.  The extensions are not included for pages that are simply *displayed* - which is most pages.

A postscript: The example page this answer originally linked to stopped existing at some point, because sometimes URIs do change, despite best practices. I've replaced it with the CDC's food safety page, which has existed in some form for [at least 20 years now](https://web.archive.org/web/20000816022511/http://www.cdc.gov/foodsafety/). Undoubtedly, numerous different technologies have served up that content over the years, while always doing so at the exact same URL.

Answer (score 14):

What you are seeing is an example of URL routing.  Instead of pointing to a specific file (e.g. page.php), the server is using a routing table or configuration that directs the request to a handler that actually renders the html (or anything else depending on the mime type returned).  If you notice, StackOverflow uses the same mechanism.

Comment: what is the practical use to url routing?

Comment: Also, it could be that 'watch' is a PHP file, and the server is just set to handle it as such even without the extension - this is how Wikipedia does it by changing 'index.php' it just 'wiki'

Comment: The practical use of URL routing is to hide the actual implementation behind the website. In the case of Web2.0-ish sites like SO, Wikipedia, Facebook, etc. that implementation can be extremely messy, or even impossible to represent as a true URL because it's a call to a web service and not a served file. Instead of all the gunk that would require, you have a relatively elegant URL to bookmark or link to in other sites.

Comment: Thanks Keith, but when you say web service, and not a direct file, what exactly do you mean?

Comment: What he means is that most frameworks work like this: `http://site.com/index.php?page=category/subcategory/pageid&param1=value1&param2=value2` to clean up the url most people use mod_rewrite to map it to: `http://site.com/category/subcategory/pageid?param1=value1&param2=value` which looks more *normal* and is friendlier to type.

Comment: To stop people from saying "PHP sucks!".

Answer (score 7):

Having or not having the extension is irrelevant. The browser acts on the MIME type returned by the server, not any extension used in the URL.

Comment: This does not really explain why some URIs don’t have a file name extension. It is not relevant for the client but it might be relevant for the server.

Comment: Not really; the server would be configured to decipher or translate the URI without the aid of an extension. For instance, the URI of this thread might end up being `http://stackoverflow.com/questions.php?&thread=3631153&title=how-come-some-site-urls-do-not-include-file-extension`. We don't have to know, because the web server, or an intermediary, does the translation. Like many shortcuts, it does mean that the site cannot use extensions to differentiate between, for instance, questions.php and questions.jsp.

Answer (score 7):

When you ask 'Why?' are you asking for a technical reason or a design reason? Some people already answered the technical so I'll just comment on the design.

Basically it boils down to that url is an endpoint. It's a place that users/services need to get to. The extension is irrelevant in most cases. If a user is browsing the web and goes to http://site.com/users he is expecting a list of users. He doesn't care that it doesn't say .html or .php. And as a designer using those extensions doesn't really make sense. You want your app to make sense, and those extensions aren't really providing any insight that the user needs.

Times that you would want to use them were if you were creating a service that other applications would use. Then you could choose to use an extension to denote what kind of data one could expect to get back (.json, .xml, etc). There are people working on design guidelines and specs for this stuff, but it's all early

Basically those extensions are used because that's how web servers/clients worked by default. As web development has matured we started treating urls more professionally and tried to make them make sense to people reading/using them.

Answer (score 5):

While extensions don't matter to the browser, which just uses the headers passed along to it to determine what to display and how to display it, chances are they **do** matter on the server. For instance, your box could have both a php and a ruby interpreter installed, but your webserver has configuration files to map file extensions to MIME types. For instance, from Apache's php5.conf:

```
  AddType application/x-httpd-php .php .phtml .php3
```

which tells Apache that files ending in .php, .phtml and .php3 should be recognized as being PHP files.

However, since the extensions don't mean anything to the client, URLs often look "nicer" without them. In order to do so, technologies such as Apache's [`mod_rewrite`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html) can be used to "rewrite" client-land URLs to have meaning on the server.

For instance, you could set up `mod_rewrite` rules to rewrite a URL like `http://yourblog.com/article/the-article-you-wrote` (which looks nicer and is simpler to type and remember) to `http://yourblog.com/articles.php?title=the-article-you-wrote`, which Apache can use to properly route the request to your PHP script.

Answer (score 2):

The key is the HTTP response header's `Content-Type` field. Something like that:

```
HTTP 200 OK
Content-Type: video/flv
Content-Length: 102345

DATA-DATA-DATA-DATA-DATA-DATA-....
```

See also:

```
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=genome.jpeg;
     modification-date="Wed, 12 Feb 1997 16:29:51 -0500";
```

More details: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIME

Comment: when you say the key, you mean the key to how the server recognizes that file?

Comment: The response contains the MIME type in the "Content-Type" field so the web browser knows what to do with it. It will display `text/html` differently than `image/png`, and so on. The point of not having an extension is that you do not have to expose your server-side technology to the world, eg no `.php`, no `.asp`, and so on. `.html` would be incorrect because they are not static pages, only the output of "the unknown technology" is HTML.

Comment: And also, for non-technical people the `.jsp` (or whatever) is just four more unnecessary and unrecognized characters that lengthen the URL.

Answer (score 2):

Well, file extensions aren't of any use on the internet. The browser doesn't care what the file extension is. You could serve a CSS file as .avi. So why not simply leave it out? This allows for shorter URLs.

Furthermore "rewriting" a url allows for more readable urls. You may not understand `/categories.php?id=455` but you do `/455-some-category`.

If you want to do this yourself and are using Apache have a look at mod_rewrite.

Answer (score 2):

The url, should properly be considered part of the user-interface. As such, it should be designed to convey information about where the user is on the site, and the structure of the site.

A url such as:

mysite.com/sport/soccer/brazil_wins_worldcup

tells the user a lot about the structure of the site, and where he currently is. In contrast:

mysite.com/article.php?cateogry=12&articleid=371

is useless, instead it exposes irrelevant implementation-details such as which language is used to make the site, and what the id of that article is (likely stored in a database under that id)

In addition to this estethical argument (don't expose the user to irrelevant implementation-details) it also helps with making the site future-proof. Because if you never exposed your language of choice to begin with, you can later upgrade to Ruby or Python, without every link in the world that points to you, now being a 404.

Design urls to make sense for users, *and* to be future-proof.

Answer (score 1):

There are many possible answers to this. It's how your web application server(s) are configured that results in what your web browser is interpreting. There could be situations where you're using URL rewriting or routing, and as others have said, what handlers you're providing for requested URLs or extensions.

I could have a URL like "http://cory.com/this/really/doesnt/exist" and have it actually be pointing at "http://cory.com/this.does.exist.123" if I wanted to.

Comment: why would one want to use url routing out of curiosity?

Comment: URL routing lets you group related logic in a single controller file, rather than splitting it up among several stand-along PHP files.

Comment: A big one is SEO (Search Engine Optimization). Some search engines coudl care less what query string parameters a page has, but if you provide a URL that can route to a page that consumes those parameters, you've instantly got a new search result. Example: http://www.cory.com/category/555/recent might route to http://www.cory.com/category.aspx?id=555&sort=recent. Plus the URLs are much easier to read and remember. Also keep in mind that "routing" is not the same thing as "rewriting" -- you're going to see them interchanged incorrectly (as I have done).

Comment: @Cory: Could you provide reference about the SEO point? I am okay with the easier to read, more meaningful, ... But I do not believe in the SEO point ;)

Comment: it can also make URLs look nicer and easier to remember

Comment: @nikic, just check out the first few results of a search on Google, you should be able to find enough information to convince you that it does help for SEO. http://www.google.com/search?q=url+rewriting+for+seo

Comment: Old comment is old :) @Cory [an old article](http://www.seroundtable.com/archives/018319.html) as I see it, it today boils down to use url path for category, query params for content filtering/ordering.

Answer (score 1):

The normal behavior of a web server is to map the requested URI path onto a file somewhere in the document root directory. So `http://example.com/foo/bar` is simply mapped onto `/path/do/document/root/foo/bar`. Additionally, the web server needs to know how to handle a file. This is often done by the file name extension. So files with the file name extension `.php` are handled by the PHP interpreter.

Now apart from this normal behavior, most web servers have features that allow to change both the mapping (i.e. [URL rewriting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rewrite_engine)) and the way how a file without a file name extension is handled.

In case of the Apache web server, the former can be done with [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/watch$ /watch.php
```

And the latter can be done with [mod_mime](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_mime.html):

```
<File watch>
    ForceType application/x-httpd-php
</File>
```

(Ok, actually this is not mod_mime feature but a [core](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html) feature.)

Comment: ok so basically that example tells the server to map watch to watch.php, and tells the server to handle as php file, by entering mime type?

Comment: @Scarface: Yes, exactly. Both variants can be used so that `/watch` refers to a page that’s content is generated by a PHP script.

Comment: excellent, thanks gumbo for your time, I will explore using those mods.

Answer (score 0):

**Rule: File extensions should not be included in URIs**

On the Web, the period (.) character is commonly used to separate the file name and
extension portions of a URI. A REST API should not include artificial file extensions
in URIs to indicate the format of a message’s entity body. Instead, they should rely on
the media type, as communicated through the Content-Type header, to determine how
to process the body’s content.

(1)http://api.college.restapi.org/students/3248234/transcripts/2005/fall.json
(2)http://api.college.restapi.org/students/3248234/transcripts/2005/fall

(1)File extensions should not be used to indicate format preference.
(2)REST API clients should be encouraged to utilize HTTP’s provided format selection
mechanism, the Accept request header.
references: design REST api rulebook

Answer (score 0):

below it what I use in my .htaccess to make the url still run correctly without the HTML or PHP extension.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f
```

means that if the file with the specified name in the browser doesn't matching with directory (-d) or files(-f) in your webserver, then rewrite rule below

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html
```

i'm not sure how the below work but I think that after it rewrite with html and if it still not matching it then rewrite with php

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

if it still not matching it will be show 404 page.

you also can redirect 404 with the code below in .htaccess

```
ErrorDocument 404 /404.html
```

importance is the code is working in for my site.

http://mintnet.net/services

http://php.mintnet.net/home

those doesn't need the file-extension.

Answer (score -4):

"www.youtube.com/watch" is a directory of YouTube. So it can basically be written as "www.youtube.com/watch/" with the ending forward slash.

Comment: you cannot open directories, only files, an url ending at a directory assumes that you have a file called index (or something like that) configured to open when the directory is requested, for example `https://www.youtube.com/watch/` would request `https://www.youtube.com/watch/index.html` but as we see that is not the case, neither are any of the other index files, so it is most likely that youtube simply routes the address internally.