# What regex would find out if file url has certain extension

Tags: php, regex

My valid urls could look more or less like this

```
http://someurl.com/some/path/file.pdf
or 
http://someurl.com/some/path/file.pdf?param=value
or 
http://someurl.com/some/path/file.pdf?param=value&second=val
```

where the file extension could be .pdf, or some other extension like .jpg or .psd, or nothing at all.

I have the url stored without the someurl.com portion, so it's the `some/path/file.pdf` part of the url

How can I use regex to know the file extension if it is present? Is regex the right tool for this?

Comment: Technically URLs (Uniform **Resource** Locators) don't have ["extensions"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3631153/how-come-some-site-urls-do-not-include-a-file-extension) because they're not files, or not necessarily. To find out the resource/media type a `get_headers()` would be more correct. But OTOH of course, it works most of the time..

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I would use `parse_url()` and `pathinfo()`. These are the most correct functions for the job.

```
$url = 'http://someurl.com/some/path/file.pdf?param=value';

$path = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PATH);

$ext = pathinfo($path, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

var_dump($ext); // string(3) "pdf"
```

[See is on CodePad.org](http://codepad.org/YS8bfaNt).

You *could* use regex, but it will be more difficult to follow.

Answer (score 1):

You would probably need to do a HTTP HEAD request. Regex would work for sure, but you're not guaranteed to catch all cases.

For example:

http://someurl.com/some/path/file might a be a text file without extension (like on most *nix systems) and the regex would fail to provide the file extension.

Answer (score 1):

A much better option is PHP's [parse_url](http://nz.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) function:

```
$path = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PATH);
$extension = ($pos = strrpos($path, '.')) ? substr($path, $pos) : "";
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't need regex, we can just use `parse_url`.

```
$url = parse_url('http://example.com/path/to/file.php?param=value');

$extension = substr($url['path'], strrpos($url['path'], '.') + 1);
echo $extension; // outputs "php"
```

http://php.net/parse-url

http://php.net/substr

http://php.net/strrpos