# Are HTML links that target a .php script basically forms?

Tags: php, html

Normally an HTML link transfers you to another page, i.e., the browser loads in a different page. For example, an "asking help" link might be implemented with:

```
<a href="/questions/how-to-ask">asking help »</a>
```

But there are also links that target a php file, like

```
<a href="http://example.com/wp-admin/post.php?post=182&amp;action=edit" title="Edit this item">Edit</a>
```

This seems to be an entirely different animal and looks effectively like a form, where post and action values are uploaded to a form handler at

`http://example.com/wp-admin/post.php`

Is that's what happening? Are you effectively implementing a form when the link target is a .php file?

Comment: in very simple term, it is indeed a php file that process a request from the url, at "post.php", $_GET['post] will hold the value 182 (post=182) and so on, which then depending on the code, do something based on the request.

Comment: No, it is exactly the same animal. _“Are you effectively implementing a form when the link target is a .php file?”_ – no, not at all. In this example it just happens to be the case that some GET parameters are passed via the query string as well.

Answer (score 0):

> Are you effectively implementing a form when the link target is a .php file?

Not quite. You're requesting a resource from the webserver, and in the example you give (`http://example.com/wp-admin/post.php`), this "resource" is a php file. Many webservers will eliminate the file extension because it shouldn't matter to the end user how you've implemented your site, as long as they can access the page at `http://example.com/wp-admin/post`. For some more good information on URLs/URIs and file extensions check out this SO question: [How come some site urls do not include a file extension?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3631153/how-come-some-site-urls-do-not-include-a-file-extension)

Your second example (`http://example.com/wp-admin/post.php?post=182&amp;action=edit`) is adding a slight wrinkle to this, a query string. The query string is "the part of a URL containing data that does not fit conveniently into a hierarchical path structure" ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string)). In this case, the query string is passing two paramteters to the `post.php` page. The first parameter is named `post` and its value appears to be the ID of the post that you would like to view. The second parameter is `action` and the value is the action that you would like to perform on the given post, `view`, `edit` and `delete` are three likely possible values for this parameter. Once the server processes this request, it returns a page that allows you to edit the post with an ID of 182 or perhaps a page telling you that you don't have permissions to edit this post.

Answer (score 0):

Both of these cause HTTP Get Requests. One has variables and one does not.

```
<a href="/questions/how-to-ask">asking help »</a>

<a href="http://example.com/wp-admin/post.php?post=182&amp;action=edit" title="Edit this item">Edit</a>
```

Both could be created as a form with method="GET". The difference is that one has hardcoded parameters like action="edit" and title="Edit this Item". If you did this as a form you could allow the user to change the parameters such as title. Most sites of any substantial information you would want to complete as a Form and use the method="POST" attribute so that the information is a little more secure. Using HTTP Get for form posts allows for URL injection.

```
http://example.com/wp-admin/post.php?post=183&amp;action="Approved";title="This Item approved"
```