# No file extension and no get variables

Tags: php, html

I'm a new web developer, I've learned HTML, CSS, JavaScript (jQuery including server calls with AJAX to PHP or JSON), PHP.

I can build a full website and I'm good till this point but I want to know something if you can help me.

So my question is: I see, lately, the good websites in the address bar there is no `.php` or `.asp` or `.html` or a get variable like (`?search=query` or `?id=5&some_other_get_variables`), in the address bar of these sites I find like *folder slash* (`domainname.com/search/query`).

I just want to know what kind of web development is this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How come some site urls do not include a file extension?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3631153/how-come-some-site-urls-do-not-include-a-file-extension)

Comment: i didn't even know how to ask the question this is why i created new one , thank you

Comment: This is usually part of an MVC (Model -> View -> Controller) website model. You can learn about these by using a framework like CodeIgniter.

Comment: i know about MVC and i only use it since i knowed it , but i've never used a php framework before

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Frameworks like CakePHP and Laravel do this. They do all of that routing internally and it keeps the URL's "pretty."

You'll see that Wordpress can do some of this too.

The important thing to remember is that as long as the web server understands a request, you'll get the correct page. The browser doesn't care about file extensions, etc.

Comment: thank you i got it , and i minded to learn Laravel in next month

Comment: Please mark my answer as complete and give an up vote. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

That some other variables in URL are "GET" parametres. You know, when you are creating simple form in HTML, you can define method (POST or GET). When you do GET, the parametres are written to URL, so you can access them easily, on other hand, it can be rewritten by user, so POST is more secure way.

The .asp is from ASP.NET, it's a website written in objective programming (like C#). Hmmm I think it's really interesting thing (ASP.NET), when you are programming in .asp, you can create easilly a mobile phone app connected to your website, because the app (is in objective programming -> C#) and .asp is in objective programming too.

Those are very basic informations, for more you should check documentation etc.

Hope i helped you,
have a nice day ;)